# How many rectangles can fit in a polygon with n-sides?

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, packing-problem, polygons

I am trying to write an algorithm to solve a problem I have. I have a few ideas of what the algorithm might be like but I am posting to see if anyone else has a better more efficient solution or any helpful suggestions. For context, this algorithm is going to be for maximising the number of solar panels that can be placed on a roof.

Given a polygon with n-sides with coordinates $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2) .....(x_n, y_n)$, how many rectangles of dimension (for example) $1\times3$ can fit within this shape?

The orientation of the rectangle can be portrait or landscape but must be consistent throughout. They are also to be arranged in a grid pattern.

At the moment my half solution is to "cut" the polygon into "strips" of, let's say, $1$ unit and see how many can fit on that and continue until all the strips are done. Alternatively, for simple polygons with a low "$n$", finding the largest rectangle that can fit within the polygon and fill it? I am keen to work out the coordinates of the rectangle that can fit in the polygon in the final solution!

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated,

Kelvin.

**EDIT:** I am probably looking towards a more simple and crude solution rather than a complex and more accurate method (as I am a geographer and therefore my maths skills are a bit limited!)

Comment: This question has been seen [over at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516044/fill-arbitrary-2d-shape-with-given-set-of-rectangles). Also, when you mention "must be consistent throughout", do you mean that all rectangles must be portrait or that their edges can only be perpendicular/parallel with each other (no weird angles)?

Comment: Thank you @Zairja for linking me to that thread!

Comment: When I mention "consistent throughout" I mean the rectangles must all be portrait or landscape and also be parallel with each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been [mentioned over at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516044/), this problem is very difficult from a computational perspective. It may help to see what methods have been implemented for the [packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem). There are [some algorithms](http://www.csc.liv.ac.uk/~epa/) out there, but you may have to fine-tune one to fit your needs.

Even a naive, greedy approach may end up being pretty inefficient. Would you take into account things like rotating the shape? There are all kinds of trade-offs to be made, but your "slices" (first fit) approach may work if you need something quick and dirty.

[image: rotate]